# Compiling 2 c files into one program and permission is denied

Tags: linux, compiling, c, gcc

My mission is to complile 2 c files into one executable program.
The purpose of this program is when called from within the terminal followed by 2 numbers the output should display the sum of these 2 numbers.

I use this command to compile the 2 files.

```
sudo gcc main.c | gcc -c my_add.c -o mainprog
```

But when called from the terminal with this command "./mainprog 2 5" I get a error message saying "permission denied"

Any insight is appreciated.

This is the first c file "main.c"

```
#include "my_add.c"
#include "my_add.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  a = atoi(argv[1]);
  b = atoi(argv[2]);

  add(a, b);
  return 0;
}
```

This is the second c file "my_add.c"

```
#include "my_add.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int add(inte a,int b) {
  sum = a+b;
  printf(" The sum of %d and &d is; %d\n" , a,b,sum);
}
```

This is my header file "my_add.h"

```
#ifndef __MY_ADD_H__
#define __MY_ADD_H__

int add(int x, int y);
int x;
int y;
int sum;

#endif
```

Comment: My first guess is that, since you are using sudo for some reason to compile the program,  the root account's `umask` creates the file without world-execute permissions. Either run `sudo chmod 0755 mainprog` or compile without using sudo. I would suggest that this is an unnecessary use of sudo.

Comment: what's wrong with `gcc -o mainprog main.c my_add.c` ?

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a fairly basic C programming excercise.

The aim of it is probably to teach you how to first *compile* two or more source code files (`*.c`) into *object files* (`*.o`) separately, and then *link* them together into a single executable program.

With larger programming projects, this can be important to minimize the compilation time after doing just a small change: only one object file will need to be recompiled, the rest can be used as-is from a previous compilation attempt.

Using `#include "my_add.c"` defeats this idea, as it forces the compiler to include all the code from one `.c` file into the other one. **You should never `#include` any `.c` files**, unless you're doing procedurally-generated code or something advanced like that. And even then, it's bad style.

The first part of your pipeline, `gcc main.c | ...` will attempt to compile just the `main.c` and will produce an `a.out` file (if there are no errors in `main.c`). Only the *compiler messages* will be piped to the second part of the pipeline, which will have no use for them.

The second part, `... | gcc -c my_add.c -o mainprog` will produce a file named `mainprog`, but it will only contain the code from `my_add.c`. It will ignore the piped output from the previous part. As a result, the `mainprog` will not actually be a valid executable program, because it will contain no `main()` function from which the program execution should begin.

You can confirm this with the command `file mainprog`, which should output something like this (the exact output may vary according to your system architecture and OS version):

```
mainprog: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

If you compare this to the output you'll get with e.g. `file /bin/ls`, you'll notice that the output from `file /bin/ls` will include the important word `executable`, while `file mainprog` won't show that word.

Only programs for which the `file` command lists as `executable` are actually complete programs: the `gcc -c my_add.c -o mainprog` will actually produce a `my_add.o` file, but the `-o mainprog` option will force it to be renamed to `mainprog`.

The expected solution should have:

- one `gcc -c <filename>.c` command for each `.c` file, producing a corresponding `<filename>.o` file.
- and one `gcc -o mainprog <filename1>.o <filename2>.o` command to link the `.o` files together into a complete executable file.

Comment: The first part of the pipeline doesn't seem to create a `main.o` file, there's no `-c` option.

Comment: @OskarSkog Oops. Without that option, it would create either an `a.out` file, or nothing if there is an error in the `main.c` file.

Comment: @telcoM Thank you for the explanation. I now understand what I was doing wrong and tried using your instructions and it became more clear and this will help me in future practice

Answer (score 2):

> `sudo gcc main.c | gcc -c my_add.c -o mainprog`

- Stop using `sudo`.
- Stop piping.
- Use the correct option `-c` on first invocation.
- Do link stage separately.

Possible correct steps (from what I can work out from the question)

```
gcc -c main.c
gcc -c my_add.c
gcc main.o my_add.o -o prog
```

There are other errors in the source code. These should come to light, when you see the error messages from the working compilation.

Comment: This is what I came up with that worked for me. "gcc -c my_add.c | gcc main.c -o mainprog" What is wrong with piping here?

Comment: @Zetzki everything is wrong with piping. You don't pipe compiler output (or input, for that matter)

Comment: @Zetzki in other words, the piping does absolutely nothing useful here and may in fact hide some compiler messages (or mix them together with messages from another file) that you would need to figure out an error in the code. In short, it would make your work harder for no reason. In a large project, it would also unnecessarily couple the various compilation steps together, making the process of recompiling the entire programming project more inefficient.

Comment: When you say "works for you". Have you tested it? (including running the code)

Comment: It's worse than "_the piping does absolutely nothing useful here_" as the two processes will run concurrently and your second stage linking may take an older version of the object file than the current compilation is producing

Comment: To answer "It works for me … What is wrong with pipes here?". A lack of error messages is not enough to be successful. It must also do what you want it to do. Try to run the output program.